# match and group sets of similar strings in a loop

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I am trying to match and group similar strings from a list but I'm not sure how to approach this.

I have the following list:

```
tablenames =[
            'SCS_q104',
            'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_1}].SCS_q102_grid',
            'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_2}].SCS_q102_grid',
            'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_3}].SCS_q102_grid',
            'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_4}].SCS_q102_grid',
            'SCS_q105',
            'SCS_q106',
            'SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_1}].SCS_q107_grid',
            'SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_2}].SCS_q107_grid',
            'SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_3}].SCS_q107_grid',
            'SCS_q108',
            'SCS_q109',
            ]
```

Expected outcome:

```
groupofgrids = [[
        'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_1}].SCS_q102_grid',
        'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_2}].SCS_q102_grid',
        'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_3}].SCS_q102_grid',
        'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_4}].SCS_q102_grid',
        ][
        'SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_1}].SCS_q107_grid',
        'SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_2}].SCS_q107_grid',
        'SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_3}].SCS_q107_grid',
        ]]
```

From the expected outcome above you can see how I would like to group the strings.
if everything before and after the brackets are the same as the string before then they belong to the single group.

There are two groups in this example.

The expected outcome has to simply group the matching set of strings, doesn't really matter if its stored as a list of lists or dict of some kind.

My attempt so far:

```
groupofgrids = []
for item in tablenames:
    if "." in item:
        suffix = item.split(".")[-1]
        if suffix in item:
            groupofgrids.append(item)

print groupofgrids
```

This method doesn't really group the set of similar strings as I wanted simply because I not sure how to.

Any advice?

Comment: What is the criteria for grouping?

Comment: @thefourtheye = see updated explanation. if everything before "[" and after "]" is the same as the string before it then they belong to the same group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the similarity is based on the string other than the contents between the brackets `[...]`, extract those sub-strings, join them using a separator(here I've used `"-"`) and use that as a key to the dictionary 
Try this -

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(.*?)\[.*?\]\.(.*)')
groupofgrids = {}
for item in tablenames:
    matches = regex.findall(item)
    if (len(matches) > 0 and len(matches[0]) == 2):    
        key = "-".join(matches[0])
        if key in groupofgrids:
            groupofgrids[key].append(item)
        else:
            groupofgrids[key] = [item]
import json
print json.dumps(groupofgrids,sort_keys=True, indent=4)
#OUTPUT
'''
{
    "SCS_q102-SCS_q102_grid": [
        "SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_1}].SCS_q102_grid", 
        "SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_2}].SCS_q102_grid", 
        "SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_3}].SCS_q102_grid", 
        "SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_4}].SCS_q102_grid"
    ], 
    "SCS_q107-SCS_q107_grid": [
        "SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_1}].SCS_q107_grid", 
        "SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_2}].SCS_q107_grid", 
        "SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_3}].SCS_q107_grid"
    ]
}
'''
```

If you want a nested list, then do this -

```
li = groupofgrids.values()
print json.dumps(li,sort_keys=True, indent=4)
#OUPTUT
'''
[
    [
        "SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_1}].SCS_q107_grid", 
        "SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_2}].SCS_q107_grid", 
        "SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_3}].SCS_q107_grid"
    ], 
    [
        "SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_1}].SCS_q102_grid", 
        "SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_2}].SCS_q102_grid", 
        "SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_3}].SCS_q102_grid", 
        "SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_4}].SCS_q102_grid"
    ]
]
'''
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works fine but I wonder if you can edit this so it doesn't rely on "." to split the string? Ideally I want to say "if everything before "[" and everything "]" is the same in a string then do this".

Comment: @Boosted_d16 you mean everything outside the "[]"??

Answer (score 0):

Is this works for you:

```
group = dict()

for elm in tablenames:
    try:
        f,s = elm.split('.')
    except:
        pass
    else:
        group.setdefault(s,[])
        group[s].append(elm)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(group.values())
```

Output:

```
[['SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_1}].SCS_q107_grid',
  'SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_2}].SCS_q107_grid',
  'SCS_q107[{SCS_q107$_$_$SCS_q107_3}].SCS_q107_grid'],
 ['SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_1}].SCS_q102_grid',
  'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_2}].SCS_q102_grid',
  'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_3}].SCS_q102_grid',
  'SCS_q102[{SCS_q102$_$_$SCS_q102_4}].SCS_q102_grid']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! much appreciated.